# Last value corresponding to each key sent on a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have a Kafka topic configured on which we publish accumulated reports for each stock we traded throughout the day. 
For example Stock A - Buy-50, Sell-60, Stock B - Buy-44, Sell-34 etc. The key while publishing is RIC code of the stock.

The next day I want all consumers to get the last published positions for each stock individually. I want to understand how to configure Kafka producer/consumer to achieve this behavior.

One thing that comes to mind is creating a partition for each stock, this will result into individual offsets for each stock and all consumers can point to the HIGHEST offset and get the latest position.

Is this the correct approach or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I think another option is to specify a random consumer-id every time a consumer connects, this will make Kafka return all the latest values for all keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work, but only if you don't care about the time boundaries too much - for example, you do not need to get the counts for each day separately, with a strict requirement that only events that happened between say, [01/25/2017 00:00 - 01/26/2017 00:00] must be counted.

If you do need to get counts per day in a strict manner - you could try using Kafka Streams , with the key of RIC and the window set to 24 hours based on the event timestamp.

This is just one other way to do that - I'm sure there are more approaches available!

Comment: Thanks @Marina for sharing tip about Kafka streams, we don't have a time based requirement. 
Just need to consume the last known state of each RIC.
Is that possible to achieve using just one partition?

Comment: if you are not interested in time boundaries and only care about the latest state - I would just use  local cache in yoru consumers, backed by Redis or Postgres to store this info, and keep updating it as you get events from Kafka. Kafka is great for scalable and very fast event "moving" - it's not really designed to be used as a store to run queries against....

Comment: Yeah, that's another approach, though my concern with this approach is - 1. Another state to maintain
2. Additional hardware
3. IO can be a bottleneck 

Ideally I would want kafka to provide me the last value for each key.